# scaling webworks app for blackberry 10 os done using html and javascript

Tags: html, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

i have done an ap using html and javascript for blackberry 10 os.when i submitted in appworld,i got the following error
Please fix the following issue(s) and resubmit your application as a new release.

I am testing your app on the BlackBerry Dev Alpha Device (OS version 10.0.9.1103). After launching the app, it doesn't appear properly on the device as it launch on portrait mode and it appears to small on the screen (30% on the top screen). Please fix the scaling issue.

Answer (score 1):

here is the recommended way of setting the initial scaling for now, include this in your  of index.html

```
<!-- new way of setting the meta tag -->
<script>
  var meta = document.createElement("meta");
      meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
      meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```